# Upscaling and Fadeout effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a certain div in my webpage.
On hover of the div I want it to upscale and fadeout at the same time. I am using CSS and Jquery.
This is my fiddle-->http://jsfiddle.net/tDATq/

Currently the effect is the text upscales and then fades out. I want it simultaneously. Also the text in the div looses it position while upscaling. Please help

Here is the code
HTML

```
<div id="tweets" class='fade'>
        Hello World
    <div>
```

CSS

```
#tweets{
    width:250px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:30px;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#00eaff;
}
#tweets:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.0);
          transform: scale(2.0);
}
```

JQUERY

```
$("div.fade").hover(
 function(){$(this).fadeOut(1900);
            }

);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need jquery for that, here is the css solution

```
#tweets{
    width:250px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:30px;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#00eaff;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* transition */
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -ms-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}
#tweets:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.0);
          transform: scale(2.0);
    opacity:0;         /* fadeout */
}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tDATq/1/

update:

this fiddle the text stays in the middle

http://jsfiddle.net/tDATq/2/

Comment: Looks great. But can u also see if you can make sure the text upscales from the centre instead of moving to the left?

Comment: @AnaMaria check my second fiddle

Comment: Why do people still wanna use fancy Jquery and add load on the server if everything can be done in css.. I mean im doing it cos i was told that its better in jquery. isnt Jquery overrated??

Comment: @AnaMaria Jquery isnt overrated, it is a very good tool, but it is definitely overused. The problem in jquery lies in it's simplicity, unexperienced people will use it as a workaround.